# (Firefox) How to stop button indent on click

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, browser

I created a button on a web page and it behaves how I want it to in every browser except for Firefox. I don't want the button to indent when I click it, and it doesn't indent in every browser except for Firefox.

Here's an example of the button indent on click in Firefox:

[image]

Notice how the chevron shifts slightly to the right on click.

How do I get the button to not indent on click in Firefox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to see your code! meantime try this might be your issue
targeting only firefox and adjusting padding for button hover

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.btn:hover{
    padding: 2px;   //adjust padding might need to be 1 or ...
}
```

}